# gls with ARMA terms: not working for one combination of terms

Tags: r, nlme

I am using the gls function from nlme to fit models with various ARMA terms.
I would like to compare multiple different models to see which of the ARMA terms provides the best model.

My general model is as follows:

`fit <- gls(y  ~ x, data = na.omit(data), method = "ML", correlation = corARMA(p = 2, q = 3))`

My y and x variables are percentages.

For every model with a combination of ARMA terms from p = 1 through p = 3 and q = 1 through q =3 work fine, however, when I fit the model specified above (ARMA(2,3)) I get the following error message.

`` "Error in `coef<-.corARMA`(`*tmp*`, value = value[parMap[, i]]) :  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)" ``

If I rerun the model specifyig `method = "REML"` it works ok, but i want to compare models using log-likelihood raio tests so I will need to stick with `method = "ML"` .

Any idea what could be causing this?

Here is a `dput` output of a few lines of data:

```
structure(list(date2 = structure(c(12234, 12265, 12296, 12357, 
12509), class = "Date"), min = c(12, 114, 480, 818, 42), fai = c(0.632, 
0.707, 3.397, 7.107, 2.011), total_time = c(1237L, 3337L, 4776L, 
9385L, 3665L), min_stand = c(0.00970088924818108, 0.0341624213365298, 
0.100502512562814, 0.0871603622802344, 0.0114597544338336), total_feed = c(6234L, 
7120L, 5592L, 6252L, 2020L), perc_feed = c(0.192492781520693, 
1.60112359550562, 8.58369098712446, 13.0838131797825, 2.07920792079208
), kcal = c(99.688648314, 923.280754221, 4671.223064892, 6851.385488668, 
408.732018202), kcal_tot = c(26428.225231694, 47032.415227701, 
20824.864136682, 44505.409085806, 16408.141649702), kcal_perc = c(0.377205232057916, 
1.96307323311181, 22.4309893895724, 15.3945006447612, 2.49103175074932
), month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 10L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

My "y" variable is "perc_kcal" and my "x" is "fai".

Thank you

PS. If I do the same modeling procedure using a different response variable ("min_stand") the model fails to converge only with the same p=2 and q=3 terms.

```
Error in gls(model = min_stand ~ fai, data = na.omit(df_cum_kam), method = "ML",  : 
  function evaluation limit reached without convergence (9)
```

Comment: Could you share a dput(data) or an equivalent mock of your dataset for us to get an idea of what your dataset looks like?

Comment: Thanks Will. Looks like it didn't get pasted completely. Could you check once more?

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706143/error-with-gls-function-in-nlme-package-in-r) help?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if it would be a matter of overparameterizing my model. Even a model with a ARMA(4,4) structure seemed to work. The error messages in that post are a little different too.